# MySQL - Need help counting id's that correspond to certain in other tables

Tags: php, optimization, mysql, query-optimization

I have on table named `players`, then other tables named `tries`, `conversions`, `penalties`, `dropgoals`.

I need to get the `player_id` from `players`, then count the following:

- number of tries for `player_id` in `tries`
- number of conversions for `player_id` in `conversions`
- number of penalties for `player_id` in `penalties`
- number of dropgoals for `player_id` in `dropgoals`

And this all needs to happen in one go as there are about fifteen players for each game, the site relates to rugby.

I have tried the following, which works:

`SELECT players.player_id, players.number, CASE WHEN (COUNT(tries.player_id) = 0) THEN '&nbsp;' ELSE COUNT(tries.player_id) END AS nrTries FROM players LEFT JOIN tries ON players.player_id = tries.player_id WHERE players.team_id IS NULL GROUP BY players.player_id ORDER BY players.number`

It select all players from the `players` table and counts their tries, but as soon as I change it to the following it gives me an error:

`SELECT players.player_id, players.number, player.name, CASE WHEN (COUNT(tries.player_id) = 0) THEN '&nbsp;' ELSE COUNT(tries.player_id) END AS nrTries FROM players, player LEFT JOIN tries ON players.player_id = tries.player_id WHERE players.player_id = player.player_id AND players.team_id IS NULL GROUP BY players.player_id ORDER BY players.number`

**It gives the following error:**

`Unknown column 'players.player_id' in 'on clause'`

Can someone please help me with this, I have been struggling for days now?

Thanks in advance

**// edit:**

Hi, all, I feel very stupid now, this code works brilliantly, except that when a player has scored in more than one type, say tries and conversions, or tries and penalties, it miscounts the number of each type, and they are made all the same.

Let's say my player scored 1 penalty and 3 dropgoals, it outputs as 3 penalties and 3 dropgoals, I can't figure out what's wrong.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT players.player_id, players.number, player.name, player.surname,
CASE WHEN (COUNT(tries.player_id) = 0) THEN '& nbsp;' ELSE COUNT(tries.player_id) END AS nrTries,
CASE WHEN (COUNT(conversions.player_id) = 0) THEN '& nbsp;' ELSE COUNT(conversions.player_id) END AS nrConversions,
CASE WHEN (COUNT(dropgoals.player_id) = 0) THEN '& nbsp;' ELSE COUNT(dropgoals.player_id) END AS nrDropgoals,
CASE WHEN (COUNT(penalties.player_id) = 0) THEN '& nbsp;' ELSE COUNT(penalties.player_id) END AS nrPenalties
FROM players
LEFT JOIN tries ON players.player_id = tries.player_id AND tries.game_id = '$game_id'
LEFT JOIN conversions ON players.player_id = conversions.player_id AND conversions.game_id = '$game_id'
LEFT JOIN dropgoals ON players.player_id = dropgoals.player_id AND dropgoals.game_id = '$game_id'
LEFT JOIN penalties ON players.player_id = penalties.player_id AND penalties.game_id = '$game_id'
LEFT JOIN player ON players.player_id = player.player_id
WHERE players.player_id = player.player_id AND players.team_id IS NULL AND players.game_id = '$game_id'
GROUP BY players.player_id ORDER BY players.number
```

***Please note:*** $game_id is a PHP variable.
***Also:*** I have included a space between & and nbsp; otherwise it does not get ouputted to SO.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why are you not following previous suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't my third answer cover this? Can you please clarify your data and what's wrong because I don't really understand your further edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused why you stated Cletus had the correct solution, and proceeded to not use it while updating your original question. That said, Cletus' solution is slightly off, you need COUNT() not SUM(). Try the following:

```
SELECT players.player_id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tries WHERE player_id = players.player_id) tries,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM penalties WHERE player_id = players.player_id) penalties
FROM players;
```

This will return 0's instead of &nbsp I'd recommend handling that in your application code though. You can add in the CASE mess if you **really** want to get the &nbsp from mysql.

Comment: This is obviously pared down, but will work once you add the additional joins, wheres, and group by.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, I should replace my `LEFT JOIN`'s with nested `SELECT` statements only where I need to `COUNT` anything. I used `CASE` because I assumed it may be faster doing the validating in MySQL and there was no additional PHP validation necessary. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't been specific enough about the data but, assuming there is one record in each associated table per player and you're happy to show NULL if it's not there then:

```
SELECT player_id, tries, conversions, penalties, dropgoals
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN tries t ON t.player_id = p.player_id
LEFT JOIN conversions c ON c.player_id = p.player_id
LEFT JOIN penalties e ON e.player_id = p.player_id
LEFT JOIN dropgoals d ON d.player_id = p.player_id
```

This can be restated as:

```
SELECT player_id
(SELECT tries FROM tries WHERE player_id = p.player_id) tries,
(SELECT conversions FROM conversions WHERE player_id = p.player_id) conversions,
(SELECT penalties FROM penalties WHERE player_id = p.player_id) penalties,
(SELECT dropgoals FROM dropgoals WHERE player_id = p.player_id) dropgoals
FROM players p
```

Performance may or may not vary depending on your database engine. If you need to sum this then change it to:

```
SELECT player_id
(SELECT SUM(tries) FROM tries WHERE player_id = p.player_id) tries,
(SELECT SUM(conversions) FROM conversions WHERE player_id = p.player_id) conversions,
(SELECT SUM(penalties) FROM penalties WHERE player_id = p.player_id) penalties,
(SELECT SUM(dropgoals) FROM dropgoals WHERE player_id = p.player_id) dropgoals
FROM players p
```

Any of the above can use IFNULL() or similar functions to return 0 instead of NULL, if desired.

Comment: Thanks Cletus, I just tried that multiple left joins, and it worked! Just checked for any new answers, and saw you had the solution as well, thanks for your trouble, you really are on of the best.

Comment: Hi, Cletus, sorry for removing the solution to your answer, because, well, it did count the types of scoring, but ultimately did not solve my question.

Answer (score 0):

Why does the second query reference "player"? I don't see you mention such a table anywhere else... ("FROM players, player") Just making sure that's deliberate.

It might be helpful to avoid mixing explicit joins (eg "LEFT JOIN") with implicit joins (eg "FROM players, player"), in order to keep your structure consistent.

Comment: I need the player name from the `player` table, I reference it before the `CASE` statement